# cannot add cefsharp to wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, cefsharp

I installed cefsharp using nuget

and followed the tutorial on the link below

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/881315/Display-HTML-in-WPF-and-CefSharp-Tutorial-Part

but i can't make it work.

currently im using .net framework 4.5.2

[image]

i also build the program. i can also run the program, but it doesn't show the webbrowser.

i also add the namespace: `xmlns:cefSharp="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"`

the screenshot of the error is below

[image]

Comment: did you tried  clean and Rebuild..

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/tree/master/CefSharp.MinimalExample.Wpf for a working example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error only occurs when you have opened Visual Studio WPF designer ([wiki CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#Wpf_designer)). When you run program everything will be ok.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

it seems you didn't added referecnces to your project, first add references and then include them into your code.